# How to correctly throw an exception

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to account for possible errors that might come up in my program. I'm creating a calculator and converting the inputs from infix to postfix to calculate the result. I want to try accounting for mismatched parenthesis in the input, but I'm having trouble. For example, when converting from infix to postfix, when a `)` is reached, it will pop numbers from the stack and put them onto the new postfix list. In one case where there may not be a matching left parenthesis present (the while loop reaches the end of the stack without coming across a `(`, it should throw an exception. I've implemented the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    else if(tok.equals(")")){
      while(stack.peek().equals("(") == false){
        try{
          Operator o = stack.pop();
          nlist.add(o);                
        } catch(EmptyStackException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        stack.pop();
      }
```

Then in the other file which constructs the GUI and processes the inputs, I entered:

```
try{
  java.util.List<Token> postfix = ExpressionManager.infixToPostfix(infix);
  // build the expression
  Expression exp = ExpressionManager.buildExpression(postfix);
  // display the results
}catch(ArithmeticException e){
     entryField.setText(e.getMessage())
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's not working. Can you give us some input and output?

Comment: As an aside, try to avoid using x == true and y == false. Just use x and !y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack.peek()` throws `EmptyStackException` before you enter inside try-catch block (I assume you expect that `pop` will throw the exception).

Second block doesn't show how the `ArithmeticException` is thrown, so, not sure what you expecting here.

Comment: Would the while loop throw an error if the list is empty when it checks the top element of the stack? Or does it just exit the loop?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I moved the if statement outside the while loop and threw the `EmptyStackException`. I didn't realize that it wouldn't pass the while loop condition once the stack was empty. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-throw an exception you can do

```
catch(EmptyStackException e){
    throw new ArithmeticException("empty stack, bad mathematical expression.", e);
}
```